# Does there exist a function for which $\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}$ is defined and where $f(a)$ is diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

> Does there exist a function for which $\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}$ is defined and where $f(a)$ diverges?

My thoughts are no since $$g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

and its area function is $$G(x)=\log(f(x))$$

and since $G(x)$ diverges at $x=a$, then $g(x)$ must also?

Comment: Intuitively, differentiation is a sort of anti-smoothing operator, so if $f(a)$ diverges, then this usually means that $f'(a)$ diverges faster at the same point, so usually if $f(a)$ diverges, then so does $f'(a)/f(a)$. I don't know how to rigorously prove this though.

Comment: Does "$f(a)$ diverges" mean $f(a)$ fails to converge as $a \to \infty$ or does it mean $f(x)$ fails to converge as $x \to a$?  If the latter, what does $f'(a)$ mean?

Comment: Since $(\ln(f(x)))'|_{x=a}$ exists, then $\ln(f(x))$ is continuous at $x=a$. In particular it is bounded on a neighborhood of $x=a$. It follows that $f(x)=e^{\ln(f(x))}$ is also bounded on a neighborhood of $x=a$.

Comment: What do you mean with "a function diverges" ...at a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no differentiable function such that
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=+\infty \quad\mbox{and}\quad\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=L\in\mathbb{R}.$$

We may assume that $f$ is differentiable and positive in $(a,a+r]$ and $|f'/f|$ is bounded by $M$ in the same interval.

Let $(x_n)_n$ be any sequence in $(a,a+r]$ such that $x_n\to a^+$ then by the MVT, there is $t_n\in (x_n,a+r)$ such that
$$\ln(f(a+r))-\ln(f(x_n))=\frac{f'(t_n)}{f(t_n)} (a+r-x_n).$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}
|\ln(f(x_n))|&\leq |\ln(f(a+r))-\ln(f(x_n))|+|\ln(f(a+r))|\\
&\leq M (a+r-x_n)+|\ln(f(a+r))|\leq Mr+|\ln(f(a+r))|
\end{align}$$
which contradicts the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|\ln(f(x_n))|=+\infty$.